# Bootstrap Modal not fading in properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm running a laravel server and am trying to setup a bootstrap modal, i've JSFiddled the exact code and it works like a charm, however on the laravel app, it seems to be stopping mid-load.

In inspect element, I can see when the button is pressed that opens the modal, the class changes from 'modal fade' to 'modal fade in' and a couple seconds later it returns back to 'modal fade'

Could this be an issue with loading such items in my dashboard layout blade view?
If I manually change the class to 'modal panel show' It shows properly.

layouts/dash.blade.php - File

```
<!-- LAYOUT CODE IS HERE -->

<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>
        $('#modal-create').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
            console.log('modal open')
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
            var modal = $(this)
        });
    </script>
```

my_folder/a_view/test.blade.php

```
<a href="#" style="padding: 10px" class="btn btn-success has-ripple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-create">CREATE USER</a>

    <!-- MODAL START -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-create" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" style="padding-right: 17px; display: none;" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Create User</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('staff.user.create') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="floating-label" for="name">Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="name" name="name" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="floating-label" for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="email" name="email" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="floating-label" for="password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="floating-label" for="password-confirm">Confirm Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password-confirm" name="password-confirm" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="floating-label" for="usergroup">Select Usergroup</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="usergroup" name="usergroup" required>
                                        <option value="user">User</option>
                                        <option value="tester">Tester</option>
                                        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                        <option value="manager">Manager</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group fill">
                                    <label class="floating-label" for="image">Profie Image</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" placeholder="matty">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Change <a href="#"  to <button> tag and try

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene I've already tried it but please read the thread again, it is working to a certain extent, the modal just never appends the modal fade show, gets stuck at modal fade in

Comment: "*stopping mid-load*" - what does this mean, what happens in the browser? Have you tried a plain, copied-HTML-from-the-docs modal on an empty page in your Laravel app, with no other JS or CSS involved?  Totally wild and probably inaccurate guess - `var modal = $(this)` - `modal` seems like a potentially risky variable name to use here, have you tried using something less likely to already exist, eg `DashboardModal`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Stopping mid load in my words is meaning that when the <a> tag is pressed to open the modal, the modal code updates to the "fade in" class, then a couple seconds later returns to the "modal fade" class name. it's never appending "show" to the end like it should after fading in.

Comment: Yes, got that from the question.  I was asking what you see in the browser.  Have you tried removing `style=".. display: none;"` from the div?